# Input Validation with While Loop Statement

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a problem in-which I am checking a users input. If its not within a specific range, then it will prompted the user again and clarify the parameter range. 
I am curious why my below code doesn't work.

```
current_speed = int(input("What is the current speed (in mph 51 - 60)? "))

while 51 > current_speed > 60:
    current_speed = int(input("Please enter a speed between (51 - 60 mph): "))
```

The user should be promoted to re-enter a speed until it meets the specified criteria.  In this example the user needs to enter a speed between `51` and `60` mph before they can break out of the `while` loop.

Comment: change `while 51 > current_speed > 60:` to `while not(51 < current_speed < 60):`

Comment: Your loop condition is wrong.  You're reprompting if the value is less than 51 and greater than 60 (which is impossible), so it never reprompts.  You probably wanted `while current_speed < 51 or current_speed > 60:` instead.

Comment: As you are new to the community I should tell you that, whichever answer works for you or you find best, use a green checkmark to accept it. Other answers you can upvote so that other people can find it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You weren't checking the numbers correctly.

```
current_speed = int(input("What is the current speed (in mph 51 - 60)? "))

while 51 > current_speed or current_speed > 60: 
    current_speed = int(input("Please enter a speed between (51 - 60 mph): "))
```

Comment: Mason, thank you for your input.  After reading your comment, I see what I was doing wrong.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
current_speed = int(input("What is the current speed (in mph 51 - 60)? "))

while current_speed > 60 or current_speed < 51:
    current_speed = int(input("Please enter a speed between (51 - 60 mph): "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a practice of writing conditions in parenthesis and checking multiple conditions separately.

```
current_speed = int(input("What is the current speed (in mph 51 - 60)? "))

while (current_speed < 51 or current_speed > 60):
    current_speed = int(input("Please enter a speed between (51 - 60 mph): "))
```